# Creating a secure website using PHP, PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

I am a computer engineering student. I got my first e-commercial web programming and design freelance business. I have some questions because i am newbie:

Is it secure to use PHP and PDO? What should I do to avoid being hacked?

It will have monetary transfers, balance and etc. If the website is hacked, or database is hacked, I will fail in the beginning of my career. Can you give advice for protecting my web site?

I will use HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap3, PHP, PDO, Mysql, JS, jQuery.

Comment: this looks like too broad question for the site. Just my humble opinion: if you ask this question, and ask it the way you do, you shouldn't be in charge of the website's security, not at least before several months of studying it seriously. The subject is vast and complex, and sometimes not really documented, on purpose. Keeping up to date with everyday evolutions is aleady some work..

Comment: Well, being a student with no knowledge or experience, you simply should NOT take a job involving security risks. Why people never have an idea to fly a jet plane after their first day in the flight school, but every CS student thinks he'll write Facebook just as a hobby?

Comment: Regarding your question: *It's not a wand, it's a wizard.* Means the tools named here will let you write a perfectly secure application, *if* you have an idea how to use them.

Comment: I agree with @YourCommonSense - you're not prepared for such a job and it would be irresponsible to take it. Handling payments and sensitive data is not a joke, and you can't just ask strangers on the internet how to avoid getting hacked. If you have even the slightest doubt in how to write secure code, then don't even try to do it for anything else but personal experiments. Plus, your question is way too broad; security is an entire field in its own right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine if you hired an electrician to rewire your house, and he showed up with no training and no tools, and he said, "I wonder how I can do this without making your house burn down, LOL!"

You would probably be uneasy about his lack of experience, and you'd be reluctant to let him try. He should instead go get some schooling and work as an apprentice to an experienced electrician for at least a few years until he learns how to do electrical wiring safely.

Frankly, you are not ready to implement a site that takes payments if you're asking beginner questions like "What should I do to avoid being hacked?"

Security is not achieved by using the "right language." It's the developer who uses the language either in a secure or insecure way. Every language can be used to develop a secure site, or else misused to develop an insecure site.

Here are some recommended resources for an introduction to software security:

- [Essential PHP Security](http://phpsecurity.org) website and the book
- [OWASP - The Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [24 Deadly Sins of Software Security: Programming Flaws and How to Fix Them](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071626751)

I agree with the comment above that taking payments is serious business. If you are hacked, you expose yourself to a lot of personal liability. That means you would have to compensate the people who lost money due to your hacked site.

I'm a software developer with many years of experience, but if I were starting a website, I would not want to take the risk that I do something wrong. I would rather spend my time on my own code and business value.

There are now services that will do payment processing for you. You can call their API in your own code, and just ask them to process payments for you, with assurance that they have developed their payment processing with expert-level security and full regulation compliance.

Here's some references that list payment processors that support your country, Turkey:

- https://www.analyzo.com/search/Payment-Gateways-Turkey/311
- https://www.shopify.com/payment-gateways/turkey
- https://www.thepaypers.com/payment-service-providers/turkey/19
- https://www.shopio.com/payment-gateways/

I have no experience personally with any of the payment processors, so I can't recommend which one will work for you. You need to read about their features and fees and decide for yourself.

Also, you should still learn about secure web programming. You're still responsible for the security of your site. You need to make sure someone can't hack into one of your users' accounts and start a payment transaction in their name, for example. But by using an API, at least you don't have to do the payment part yourself, which is much harder.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, there's Procedural PHP and PDO PHP. Use PDO because its compatible with many databases including Oracle. PDO is newer technology. To add on use prepared statements when writing PDO to prevent SQL injection. As for the rest, use whatever language. You must be secure on both the client-side (html, javascript etc) and the server-side (PHP).